# I having issues is storing image field data in jquery cloning with laravel5.8

Tags: jquery, laravel, laravel-5.8, cloning, foreach-loop-container

I have `name`, `email` and `image` input fields in a view file. I use jquery cloning in the view file. How to store the `image`, `name` and `email` values in the database by using laravel 5.8 creating a method?

This is my code:

```
public function addMorePost(Request $request) {
    $request->validate([
       'addmore.*.name' => 'required',
       'addmore.*.qty' => 'required',
       'addmore.*.price' => 'required',
       'addmore.*.image' => 'required',
    ]);

    foreach ($request->addmore as $key => $value) {
        ProductStock::create($value);
    }

    return back()->with('success', 'Record Created Successfully.');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use the foreach container to loop through the request variables .
Just get all the input variables by using,

```php
$data = $request->all();
```

And then store into db by using `$data` variable .

```php
ProductStock::create($data);
```

Comment: What do you mean by clone values?

Comment: @Crazycoder I'm not able to understand your question and your question quality is low . So, I'm going to close this question as low quality